# Move git repository to another github user

Tags: git, version-control, github

There are many answers on Google that point in the same direction, but when it comes to version control I don't want to try anything and then mess up my repository.

I have set up a repository on GitHub and would like to move it to another user, so that I can close the repository. He would then invite me to the repo once it belongs to his account. I guess this is quite a common use case for working with clients - once you finished the project, you hand it over to them.

Now, assuming this is possible, how would I change my local Git settings in the project so that I am now pushing to/pulling from the new location? And, by moving the repo, would I lose the commit history?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Any of the following will work:

- Just transfer ownership of the repo to another user and have them add you as a collaborator.
- If someone forks your repo, then you delete the original, their fork is still there, *unless it's a private repository*. they can then add you as a collaborator on their fork repo.
- Another user can simply clone your repo (commits intact), create a new repo on GitHub, add the new repo's remote info, and push your repo up to their new one. (Then, they can add you as a collaborator.)

Comment: Just want to correct something in the chosen answer by xero. Github documentation says: "Delete the repository which will delete ALL forks. Note that this only affects private repositories, not public ones." So it looks like the above comment, "but if someone forks your repo then you delete the original, their fork is still there," is not correct if the repo is private.

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/what-happens-to-forks-when-a-repository-is-deleted-or-changes-visibility/

But if they delete with all fork, the files on users computers should be still there with full history I guess, right? So then new repository could be made. But then why fork, why not clone then? Then it would be not linked to parent as I understand.

Comment: Tried just changing remote and pushing. In my new repository there are not all branches. So I guess, the branches are which I have checked out to my computer. So now I only have idea - to checkout all branches from old repo. But this does not look like efficient way

Comment: Forking the repo does not copy the issues.

Answer (score 14):

To answer the questions:

1. You would not lose anything - not even commit history. The point of Git is that it is decentralized - everybody with a copy of the repository has everything. Just the new repo.
2. It is easy to change the git settings to push to the new repository. You can either use

   ```
   git remote set-url origin git://new.url.here
   ```

   or edit the `.git/config` file.

I would say you should:

1. Transfer ownership of the repository (or have the client fork it).
2. Change your git config to push to the new repository
3. You're done.

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you do it within github? Just transfer ownership to the new user. Go to Settings at Github.

> Transfer Ownership: Transfer this repo to another user or to an
>   organization where you have admin rights.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be as easy as it sounds - a long warning with a lot of information appears. What if I do the following: The other user sets up a fresh repo, I change the repo address locally to the new one, push, and delete my own repo. Would that work? Would the commit history be lost for the new repo?

Comment: Yes your approach will work too. You won't loose any history.

Comment: Where do we have the option to accept the transfer of a repository on our account?

Comment: @AnshulSahni frrom [GitHub docs](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/transferring-a-repository): "When you transfer a repository that you own to another personal account, the new owner will receive a confirmation email. The confirmation email includes instructions for accepting the transfer. If the new owner doesn't accept the transfer within one day, the invitation will expire."

Comment: Well I don't remember what was the scenario, since this is a very old comment, but as far as I remember, I was transferring from one of my own account to other and I wasn't receiving the email onto the receiving account

Answer (score 2):

This can also be done directly with the desktop version of GitHub on a PC without installing CLI.

As stated above by @citruspi if you edit the config file you're doing what this command does for you manually.

```
git remote set-url origin git://new.url.here
```

Does for you if you have CLI.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132101/3099982

> or edit the .git/config file.

Steps below...

1. Create /newRepo in Github or Github Desktop.
2. Clone that /newRepo to your local machine (if you didn't create it in Github Desktop).
3. Clone the repo you want to clone onto your local machine as well /wantToCloneRepo.
4. Delete the .git folder in /newRepo.
5. Copy the files from /wantToCloneRepo to the local folder /newRepo
6. Edit the file /newRepo/.git/config where the remote "origin" URL should now equal the new destination on Github. IE... https://github.com/DataAutomation/newRepo.git
7. Look up where is used to say fetch origin and it will say Push.
8. Push and it will preserve your commit history and you'll have a new repo without installing CLI.

Answer (score 0):

You would not lose anything. That's the point of git. Every copy of the project has a complete copy of the repo - you have it, github has it, anyone who forks it has it.

The configuration of the remote is just a line in the .git/config file:

```
    url = git@github.com:mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples.git
```

You can remove the old remote and create a new one, but the simplest thing is just to edit that line by hand.

There is no mystery here. The .git folder and your repository are directly open to your view.